# How to remove a whole tuple from vector with a string match?

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I am trying to remove a tuple from a vector that matches the input string.

```
vector< tuple<string, int, int> > goals;
```

So, if the string matches with the input string x, I want it to be removed.

```
void remove_goal(const string& x){
     goals.erase(remove(goals.begin(), goals.end(), x));
}
```

But I am getting this error

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>' and 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>')
            if (!(*__i == __value_))
                  ~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Can you directly compare a `string` and a `tuple` containing a `string`? I'd write a bit of test code  to make sure this is possible before continuling.

Comment: Yes, I would say so. because I am trying to compare the string from the whole tuple vector and the input string.

Comment: I was going to add a note on the error message to my answer, but then realized that the error is about a `std::tuple< std::string,std::string,int>` not about `std::tuple<std::string,int,int>`. Next time please include the real code and the complete error message.

Comment: Others already answer the question. A quick thing to mention is that you can also use `std::get<std::string>(t)` to get the string member, instead of `std::get<0>`, if you only have one element in there with the type of `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that demonstrates a fairly efficient way to delete `std::tuple`s from a `std::vector` that match a criteria.

It uses the aptly named erase/remove idiom.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, int>> v;

  v.push_back(std::make_tuple("Hello", 1, 1));
  v.push_back(std::make_tuple("Cruel", 2, 2));
  v.push_back(std::make_tuple("World.\n", 3, 3));

  v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                         [](auto s) { return std::get<0>(s) == "Cruel"; }),
          v.end());

  for (auto i : v) {
    std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << ' ';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World.
```

As you can see, you were on the right track. But you cannot directly compare a `std::string` to a `std::tuple` just because the `std::tuple` contains a `std::string`. That logic doesn't really make sense nor does it extend to other examples.

This addresses your edit where the erase occurs in a function:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

void remove_from(std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, int>>& v,
                 const std::string& val) {
  v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                         [&val](auto s) { return std::get<0>(s) == val; }),
          v.end());
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, int>> v;

  v.push_back(std::make_tuple("Hello", 1, 1));
  v.push_back(std::make_tuple("Cruel", 2, 2));
  v.push_back(std::make_tuple("World.\n", 3, 3));

  remove_from(v, "Cruel");

  for (auto i : v) {
    std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << ' ';
  }
}
```

It works because I'm just making a comparison of values held, and not attempting to modify `val` at all.

Comment: what if the string input is given as this. `const string& x`

Comment: You will have to elaborate, likely by editing your question.

Comment: Hey @sweenish, I just edited the question. Can you have a look?

Comment: @sisia Edited in an example where you pass the value to be erased to a function with a reference to const parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `operator==` to compare a `std::string` and a `std::tuple<std::string,int,int>`. You can use `std::remove_if`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector< std::tuple<std::string, int, int> > goals {{"foo",42,3141}};

    std::string x{"foo"};
    // x == goals[0];  nope !!
    // goals.erase(std::remove(goals.begin(), goals.end(), x));  // nope !!
    goals.erase(std::remove_if(goals.begin(), 
                               goals.end(),
                               [&x](auto t){
                                    return std::get<0>(t) == x;
                               }));
    std::cout << goals.size();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Y94rPf5T)