# How do I delete a tuple within a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I have been programming for 1 week and  I have a `vector<tuple<string, string, int>> edgesVector` which contains two strings and an INT. How do I delete a tuple within the vector that contains two specific strings?

The error is saying (in brief):

> no matching function for call to
> vector<tuple<string , string , int>::erase(tuple<string , string , int>)

```
remove_edge(const string& u, const string& v) {

    for (int i = 0; i<edgesVector.size(); i++ ) {
        if (get<0>(edgesVector[i]) == u && get<1>(edgesVector[i]) == v){
            edgesVector.erase(i);//error
        }
        if (get<1>(edgesVector[i]) == u && get<0>(edgesVector[i])== v){
            edgesVector.erase(i);//error
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: What relation does this code have to your question? Is that your attempt? Does it not work? Why not? Please clarify.

Comment: You should use the [erase remove idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector) to remove the elements from your vector

Comment: you don't. The vector manages the lifetime of its elements for you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please always post a  [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: Should be marked as a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67185327/6119582

Answer (score 3):

You use `std::remove_if`, and pass the result to `edgesVector.erase`. This is called the [erase-remove idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector).

```
void remove_edge(const string& u, const string& v) {
    auto it = std::remove_if(edgesVector.begin(), edgesVector.end(), [&](auto & tup){ return (get<0>(tup) == u) && (get<1>(tup) == v); }); // removes elements that match u, v
    it = std::remove_if(edgesVector.begin(), it, [&](auto & tup){ return (get<0>(tup) == v) && (get<1>(tup) == u); }); // removes elements that match v, u
    edgesVector.erase(it, edgesVector.end()); // resize the vector to only hold live elements
}
```

Comment: How about doing both tests in the same lambda? That'd make more sense

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili that makes the lambda more than twice as complicated. I prefer this way for clarity.

Comment: It seems less complicated to me as we don't need to keep track of an end iterator and we don't need the `remove_if` boilerplate twice: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v4h8jcnKh

Answer (score 0):

The *erase-remove* idiom commented by others is the way to go, but the problem with your snippet is easily solved.

[`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) takes an *iterator* as a parameter whereas you're passing it an *index*.

```
for (auto itr = edgesVector.begin(); itr != edgesVector.end();) {
    if ((get<0>(*itr) == u && get<1>(*itr) == v) ||
        (get<1>(*itr) == u && get<0>(*itr)== v))
        itr = edgesVector.erase(itr);
    else
        ++itr;
    }
}
```

Comment: This only removes one element. OP may want to remove all the matching elements

Comment: erase returns a new iterator, to the next element of the erased. So the algorithm can erase multiple elements, by some adjustments. Use `itr = edgesVector.erase(itr);`. To not skip elements, you need to increment itr only if the element is NOT erased